# "Input Not Supported" with a new installation

Tags: drivers, system-installation

I partitioned the HD on my Windows machine and installed Ubuntu on it. It's a custom built desktop for gaming, so it has some custom parts. After the installation, when it restarted into Ubuntu I'm getting "Input not supported" on the monitor.

Based on [this article](https://tutorialforlinux.com/2022/11/16/nvidia-geforce-gtx-1070-ubuntu-22-10-driver-installation/2/), it could be related to the graphic card and installing the correct driver will fix the problem. To do that how do I first get into Ubuntu? I can't seem to SSH into it.

Comment: How are we to help?  You've provided no Ubuntu product or release details, and if it's a LTS release for example, which media you used & thus which kernel stack option you've opted for. If your machine is new, you need a newer kernel stack (ie. newer kernel modules which are commonly called *drivers*). Did you perform basic checks?  ie. ISO & media verification?  If the original install media booted; did it reboot into the same kernel? or upgrade during install? and thus have you tried the install kernel (*if available*). We've got almost no details currently.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to get into Ubuntu with the "Input not supported" error is to use the `nomodeset` parameter in the GRUB menu. This parameter disables the kernel mode setting feature, which may cause problems with some graphics cards. Here are the steps to use the `nomodeset` parameter:

- Restart your computer and hold the Shift key to enter the GRUB menu.
- Select the Ubuntu option and press E to edit it.
- Find the line that starts with `linux` and add `nomodeset` at the end of it.
- Press Ctrl+X or F10 to boot with the modified option.

If this works, you should be able to see the Ubuntu desktop and install the correct driver for your graphics card. You can also make the `nomodeset` parameter permanent by editing the `/etc/default/grub` file and running `sudo update-grub`.

You can find more information on how to use the `nomodeset` parameter in this article [Input not supported](https://askubuntu.com/questions/840785/input-not-supported).

Comment: Thanks. I was able to follow all the steps but it rebooted back into the same issue. When I see the GRUB menu next time, it does not have the 'nomodeset' ie it didn't save it.